# Algebra book recommendation inverse limit, universal property

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

Could you recommend me a book in which I can read about inverse limit, universal property and things like that?

I'd really appreciate all your help. I'd prefer something as elementary as possible (I realize that the subject I'm inquiring about isn't elementary, though).

Thanks.

Comment: Try any introduction to category theory, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21128/when-to-learn-category-theory.

Comment: @Hagrid "Algebra", MacLane, Birkhoff

Comment: 2015 Update: Try Bergman's [An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-11478-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P. Grillet's *Abstract Algebra* explains categorical things like this pretty plainly.

If you wanted to go further with categories, you might try MacLane's *Categories for the working mathematician*, which everyone should give a try eventually...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'll try Grillet's book first :)

Comment: "Algebra", MacLane, Birkhoff