# Why should a combinatorialist know category theory?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, category-theory

I know almost nothing about category theory (I have just skimmed the first chapters of Aluffi's [algebra book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847813)), reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21128/when-to-learn-category-theory) got me thinking... why should someone mostly interested in combinatorics/graph theory learn category theory?

What I am asking for is examples of how knowledge of category theory might be beneficial for someone doing combinatorics.

Comment: You might be interested in [combinatorial species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species), which are most naturally described as an endofunctor on the category of finite sets and bijections.

Comment: Not beneficial. Forget it.

Comment: @Berci: could you elaborate on your rather cryptic comment?

Comment: Refer to Chris Taylor's comment on combinatorial species.

Comment: I've posted a "follow-up" question about combinatorial species [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352724/what-is-the-difference-between-analytic-combinatorics-and-the-theory-of-combinat)

Comment: Related: http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2215

Answer (score 15):

If you are interested in becoming a pioneer in a new area of mathematics that involves combinatorics then there is *Combinatorial category theory.*

László Lovász talks about this in a video interview starting at 1m59s in https://simonsfoundation.org/science_lives_video/laszlo-lovasz/?chapter=22

Also in his book *Large networks and graph limits*, chapter 23, http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/bookxx/hombook-oct-2012.pdf, there is a section on categories in which he says: "In graph theory, the use of categories (as a
language and also as guide for asking question in a certain way) has been practiced
mainly by the Prague school, and has lead to many valuable results; see e.g. the
book by Hell and Nešetřil [2004]." (Graphs and Homomorphisms)

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this, definitely!

Comment: Apparently an update for the second link, which is dead: http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/bookxx/hombook-almost.final.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You might find interesting [Extensive categories and the size of an orbit](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/30/17/30-17abs.html) by Ernie Manes (TAC, 2015).