# Is $\frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x}- \frac1{\ln x}$ related to the trivial solutions $\zeta(-2n)$?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

The Prime Counting Function $\pi(x)$ is given
$$
\pi(x) = \operatorname{R}(x^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho}) - \frac1{\ln x} + \frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x} ,
$$
with $    \operatorname{R}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \mu (n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n})$.

(At least to me) It's interesting to see, that $\operatorname{R}(x^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})$ runs over the non-trivial roots of $\zeta$ and its pole at $1$. So my question is:

> Is $\displaystyle \frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x}- \frac1{\ln x}$ related to the trivial solutions $\zeta(-2n)$?

I'm just guessing, but could this be related to $\displaystyle \sum_{n}R(x^{-2n})$, the sum over the trivial soultions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

Shortly : Yes, the 'remaining term' at the right is minus the sum on the trivial zeros : $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{R}(x^{-2n})$ so that the complete formula may be rewritten :
$$
\pi_0(x) = \operatorname{R}(x^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})
$$
with $\rho$ running over **all** the zeros of $\zeta$ (you may find affirmations that the non-trivial zeros only should be considered but I think they originated from a wrong interpretation of an approximate expression neglecting the trivial zeros...).

(for more about $\pi_0$, Gram series and $\zeta$ zeros see Matthew Watkins' entertaining page on the ['encoding' of the distribution of prime numbers](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/encoding1.htm))

The non-trivial zeros will be considered grouped by symmetrical pairs extending away from the real line (but even in this case I didn't see a proof of convergence) while the real zeros contribution is very regular and small for large $x$ so that your 'remaining term' is indeed often forgotten...

To obtain the expression for $\pi_0(x)$ let's start with Riemann's famous 'explicit formula' (the $\rho'$ are non-trivial zeros) :
$$f(x)= \operatorname{li}(x)-\sum_{\rho'} \operatorname{li}(x^{\rho'}) -\log(2)+\int_x^\infty \frac{dt}{t\left(t^2-1\right)\log(t)}$$

$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \pi_0\left(x^{\frac 1n}\right)$ so that we may use a special case of [Möbius inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) to get the converse expression ($\mu$ is the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)) :

$$\pi_0(x)=\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}n f\left(x^{\frac 1n}\right)$$ 
and apply this transformation on $f$ to each of the terms at the right :

of course $\operatorname{li}(x)$ becomes the 'Gram series' $\operatorname{R}(x)$ given by : 
$$\operatorname{R}(x)=1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\log(x)^m}{m!m \zeta(m+1)}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}n \operatorname{li}\left(x^{\frac 1n}\right)$$

the same way $\displaystyle \sum_{\rho'} \operatorname{li}(x^{\rho'})$ becomes $\displaystyle \sum_{\rho'} \operatorname{R}(x^{\rho'})$

this identity of Möbius functions $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}n=0$ allows to eliminate the constant term.

At this point we should have :
$$ \pi_0(x)= \operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho'} \operatorname{R}(x^{\rho'}) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}n\cdot\int_{x^{\frac 1n}}^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)t\log(t)}$$

we may now develop $\displaystyle \frac 1{t^2-1}$ as $\displaystyle \frac 1{t^2}+\frac 1{t^4}+\frac 1{t^6}+\cdots$ and get :

$$\int_x^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)t\log(t)}=  -\left[\operatorname{li}(x^{-2})+\operatorname{li}(x^{-4})+\operatorname{li}(x^{-6})+\cdots\right]$$
(using the integral expression of the logarithmic integral or the exponential integral...)

so that the 'remaining term' of interest to you becomes (as you supposed) : $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}n\cdot\int_{x^{\frac 1n}}^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)t\log(t)}= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{R}(x^{-2n})$$

Concerning the proposed closed form (which appears too in the rather good article ['Prime-counting function'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Formulas_for_prime-counting_functions) from Wikipedia) you may consult the fine article of Riesel and Göhl from 1970 ['Some calculations related to Riemann's prime number formula'](http://www.wstein.org/edu/2007/simuw07/misc/Riesel-Gohl-Some_Calculations_Related_to_Riemanns_Prime_Number_Formula.pdf) (p976s).

All this should show that for $\rho$ running over all the zeros of $\zeta$ we have indeed :
$$ \pi_0(x)= \operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho} \operatorname{R}(x^{\rho}) $$

(of course there should be a more direct derivation of this for example starting with Riemann's expression $f(x)$ written with trivial zeros...)

Comment: +1 thanks, so $\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho_t}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \mu (n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{\rho_t/n})$ with trvial roots $\rho_t=-2n$ is kind of a representation of $\frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x}- \frac1{\ln x}$?

Comment: @draks: shortly yes. I'll update my answer a little later with a more detailed derivation.

Comment: Thanks again Raymond: I would be glad if you could have a look at this question on [Two Representations of the Prime Counting Function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/269997/19341) as well. Cheers, draks...

Comment: First many thanks for the very generous bounty @draks !! Of course this was not necessary since the subject itself is really beautiful (I had noticed your other question and wanted to investigate it this weekend...). Cheers !

Comment: Hi Raymond, it's been a while. There popped up a question related to my question and therefore your answer. We just started a chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126926/draks-and-vitamind) and would be happy if you could help (again :-)...