# Aside from approximation functions, are there any proven functions that produce an exact $n$th prime?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

Aside from approximation functions, are there any functions that produce an exact $n$th prime?

Comment: You should say what form you are prepared to accept for the function's definition, otherwise defining $p(n)$ as "the $n$th prime number" is such a function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many [Formulas for primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes). See too MathWorld's ['Prime formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html) and Rowland's [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3217).

For example Willans' formula :
$$p_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\large 2^n}\left\lfloor\left(\frac n{\sum_{j=1}^i\left\lfloor\left(\cos\frac{(j-1)!+1}x\pi\right)^2\right\rfloor}\right)^{1/n}\right\rfloor$$
or Gandhi's formula :
$$p_n=\left\lfloor1-\log_2\left(-\frac 12+\sum_{\large{d|P_n-1}}\frac{\mu(d)}{2^d-1}\right)\right\rfloor$$
(with $\mu$ the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function))

The difficulty is to find efficient formulas (most of the previous ones are mere variations of the [Wilson theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), which means evaluating $(n-1)!\pmod{n}$ to know if $n$ is prime, or a parsing of the possible divisors up to $\sqrt{n}\,$ or $n-1$ : i.e. for one prime you need $O(n)$ or $O(\sqrt{n})$ operations).

This should be compared to the venerable sieve and more modern [primality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Sieves) (with running times in $O\bigl(k\;\log(n)^m\bigr)$) as well as modern evaluation of the [prime-counting function $\pi(n)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_.CF.80.28x.29).

Comment: Thanks. May i ask you to elaborate on what you mean by efficient.

Comment: @Babiker: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get the $n$th prime $p_n$, you could

1. calculate the infinite sum
   $$
   \pi(x) = \operatorname{R}(x^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})
   $$
   with $\rho$ running over **all** the zeros of $\zeta$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120221/19341))
2. and invert the prime counting function to get $p_n=\pi^{-1}(n)$.

Ok, I'm not sure if you have the time for 1. and a way for 2.

Comment: +1: This analytic method was considered by Lagarias and Odlyzko in their paper ['Computing $\pi(x)$: An Analytic Method'](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/analytic.pi.of.x.pdf). They considered too the method that allowed the actual evaluation of $\pi(x)$ up to $10^{23}$ : the ['Meissel-Lehmer method'](http://wstein.org/home/wstein/www/home/victor/Desktop/2007973.pdf). The latest results seem to be [here](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/pi(10%5E24).html) : up to $10^{24}$ with the analytic method! A more recent [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5712) from Platt.

Comment: without forgetting [Galway's 2004 thesis](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~galway/PhD_Thesis)...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni thank ou very much for the links...

Comment: Thanks @Draks: this was a kind of tribute to those who used the analytic method for fast evaluation (not really easy from my experience...).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I just realized that it was your answer back then...

Comment: Thanks to notice @Draks ! I was always fond of this very nice formula $\displaystyle \pi(x) = \operatorname{R}(x^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho})$ (observing that the pole at $1$ gets a plus sign while the zeros get $-1$ shows how direct the transformation from zeros to primes really is... and allows to imagine the possibility of a simple complex counting function...).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I love it...