# How does it follow $s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, integration, analytic-number-theory

I have two relations:

1)$-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$.

2)$\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)$.

From these two how does it follow that $-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx$, for $s>1$.
Can anyone explain how does it follow?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%2dStieltjes_integral#Integration_by_parts

Answer (score 6):

Let's start with the definition of the [von Mangoldt function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function) ($p$ will always mean a prime) :
$$\ \Lambda(n):=\begin{cases}
\log\, p & \text{if}\ n=p^k\ \text{and}\ k>0\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

We may use the Euler product in $\ \displaystyle\log \zeta(s)=-\sum_{p\ \text{prime}}\log(1-p^{-s})=\sum_p\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{p^{-ks}}k\ $ to obtain your first relation (after derivation) :

$$\tag{1}-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_p\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log\,p}{p^{ks}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\quad\text{for}\ \ \Re(s)>1$$

After that we want to use the definition of the [second Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) :
$$\tag{2} \psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)$$

But, using [Abel's sum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) with $a(n):=\Lambda(n)$ and $\phi(n):=n^{-s}$, we get :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}=s\int_1^\infty \frac {\sum_{n\leq x}\Lambda(n)}{x^{s+1}}\;dx$$
that is, using $(1)$ and $(2)$, the wished formula :
$$-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}{x^{s+1}}dx$$

Inverting this [Mellin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) to express $\psi(x)$ would produce [Perron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula#Proof) as shown in this [derivation of the 'explicit formula'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function/282848#282848) with better handling of the discontinuities.

Comment: Thanks @draks even if you should know much about this now ! :-) This is only a small (edited) part of this [expanded answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function/282848#282848) after all...