# Squeezing $\pi(x)$ out of $\psi(x)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can $\pi(x)$ be written in terms of $\psi(x)$? I can only seem to approximate it:

$$
\pi(x)\approx\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{\mu(n)}{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{\log(x^{1/n})}\left(\psi(x^{1/n})-x^{1/n}+\sqrt{\pi}\right)+\operatorname{li}(x^{1/n})-1\right)\right]
$$

Is there a relationship of equivalence between $\psi(x)$ and $\pi(x)$ (ie, an inversion formula), or can it only approximate it?

Out of interest I include the difference up to $10^5$ between the RHS and the LHS

[image]

and both together for very small $x$

[image]

Comment: Well known are the [three "explicit formulae"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function/282848#282848) from $(7)$ to $(11)\;$. The link gives the transformations to go from $\;\psi \to \Pi \to \pi\;$ i.e. :
$$\Pi^*(x)=\frac{\psi^*(x)}{\log \,x}+\int_2^x\frac{\psi^*(t)\ dt}{t\,\log^2 t}$$
$$\pi^{*}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(k)}k \Pi^*\left(x^{1/k}\right)$$
After substitution of the first equation (obtained using $(4)$) in the second we get :

Comment: \begin{align}
\pi^{*}(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(k)}k \left(\int_2^{x^{1/k}}\frac{\psi^*(t)\ dt}{t\,\log^2 t}+\frac{\psi^*({x^{1/k}})}{\log \,{x^{1/k}}}\right)\\
\end{align}
You may try some rewriting but the use of $\mathrm{li}$ or $\mathrm{R}$ appeared more fruitful in the past... Hoping this will help anyway,

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni, thank you! This looks great - thank you for your answer and your link! :)

Comment: Glad you liked that martin! Fine approximation btw! Cheers,

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy relation between $\pi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, namely
$$
\pi(x)=\frac{\psi(x)}{\log (x)}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2(x)}\right). 
$$
I am not sure if this is a  "better expression". There are very efficient formulas for computing $\pi(x)$, see for example [here](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml). There are similarities to your formula in section $4$.

Comment: Thanks - this is a bit simpler, but I was wondering whether there is an expression without a $O$ term? NB, I am not really interested in computing $\pi(x)$ from $\psi(x)$, (I believe it is simpler to computer from the $\zeta$ function) I am more interested in the relationship between them.

Comment: Both $\pi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ can be written in terms of the zeroes of the Riemann Zeta function. Apart from this I don't know how to express one in terms of the other by an exact formula.