# Riemann Zeta function error %?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

I've heard two conflicting stories on whether or not the Zeta function 100% accurately predicts where primes are.

So does It? Also, is there an error correction formula that makes it 100% accurate if it is not already?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are referring to here. There are many relationships between $\zeta$ and the primes. The most direct is given by the [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula) $\zeta(s) = \prod_{p~\text{prime}} (1-1/p^s)^{-1}$ for $\Re s>1$ which shows how the value of $\zeta(s)$ is determined by the location of the primes. Another one is the relationship between the *zeros* of the $\zeta$-function and the distribution of primes as given by [Riemann's explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)).

Comment: Closely related, perhaps a duplicate: [Two representations of the prime counting function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function), beginning with an exact expression for the prime counting function that depends on *zeroes* of the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 3):

The Riemann Zeta function is a huge topic in maths, but my understanding is that Schoenfeld (1976) showed that $\zeta$ can put a bound on the error of the prime number theorem with 
$$| \pi (x) - \text{Li}(x) | < \frac{1}{8\pi} \sqrt{x} \log(x)$$
Where $x \geq 2657$ and with $\pi(x)$ being the prime counting function.

Comment: So it sounds like the Riemann Zeta is decent error correction, but still not proven exact?

Comment: Exactly. It has only been able to proven that it can be a bound on the error.