# A formula for $\pi(x)$

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

I found the formula for $\pi(x)$ on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27_number

$$\pi (x)=\operatorname {li} (x)-{\frac {\operatorname {li} ({\sqrt {x}})}{2}}-\sum _{\rho }\operatorname {li} (x^{\rho })+{\text{smaller terms}}$$
What are the smaller terms?

Comment: If we knew that, the distribution of primes wouldn't be such a mystery. All we know is that they're relatively small compared to the other terms.

Comment: @Arthur Assuming you are correct, perhaps you could write an answer showing specifically what open conjectures are related to knowing those smaller terms.

Comment: People really MUST read more books, instead of posting dumb questions / writing dumb comments over here.

Comment: @6005 I have no knowledge of where the literature is at on this. It's possible that more terms are known, and I don't think my speculating on this deserves a full answer. However, I am absolutely certain that we don't know _all_ of the smaller terms.

Comment: @Jonathan: See for example $\,(9),(10),(11)\,$ from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269997/two-representations-of-the-prime-counting-function/282848#282848) (as well as $(7)$ from the other answer).

Comment: It is trivial that there are smaller terms that we do not know, for otherwise the equation would be expressed differently with the actual smaller terms *included*. Here is a video that provides a background on this sort of equation $\longrightarrow$ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lihh_lMmcDw