# Riesel and Gohl's Approximation of the Modified Prime Counting Function, $\pi_{0}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

In their article "Calculations Related to Riemann's Prime Number Formula", Riesel and Gohl claim a simplification of Riemann's evaluation of the modified prime counting function
\begin{align}
\pi_{0}(x) & = \tfrac{1}{2} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \pi(x + \epsilon) + \pi(x - \epsilon) \\ & =  \lim_{N \to \infty} R_{N}(x) - F_{N}(x)
\end{align}
where $F_{N}(x)$ is an infinite sum which depends only on the complex zeros of the zeta function in the critical strip and accounts for the discontinuities of $\pi_{0}$ at the primes, while
\begin{align}
R_{N}(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \mathsf{li}(\sqrt[n]{x}) + \frac{1}{2 \log x} \sum_{m = 1}^{N} \mu(n) + \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan \frac{\pi}{\log x} + \epsilon_{N}(x)
\end{align}
is a smooth function of $x$, and $\epsilon_{N} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. The first term is Riemann's well-known approximation to $\pi_{0}$, and the remaining terms depend only on the trivial zeros of the zeta function (at the negative even integers). One often finds the approximation,
\begin{align}
\pi_{0}(x) \approx \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \mathsf{li}(\sqrt[n]{x}) - \frac{1}{ \log x}  + \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan \frac{\pi}{\log x}
\end{align}
usually attributed to them. What of the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ and sum involving the Möbius function; doesn't this sum diverge?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They used the classical formula $$\frac 1{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$ and applied it with different values of $s$ to get :

1. $\sum_{n\ge1} \mu(n)=-2\ $ ($s=0$ and using $\zeta(0)=-\frac 12$) (warning : conjectured only!)
2. $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0\ $ ($s=1$ and since $\frac 1{\zeta(1)}=0$)
3. $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{\mu(n)\log(n)}{n}=-1\ $ (at $s=1$ with $\left(\frac 1{\zeta(s)}\right)'_{s=1}=1$ and $\left(\frac 1{n^s}\right)'_{s=1}=-\frac{\log(n)}n$)

   The transformation used was the first one in your case (with $+$ in front of the initial $\frac 1{\log(x)} \sum \mu(n)$ I think).

   But this doesn't seem satisfying for a proof since Hardy wrote about (2) that it was as "deep" as the prime number theorem (in "Ramanujan" page 24, I think that (2) was proved by Landau, for a recent review see Terence Tao's ["A remark on partial sums involving the Möbius function"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.4323v5.pdf)).

   Concerning your first sum this wikipedia article about the [Mertens function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function) should be helpful.
   If we define the Mertens function as $M(n)= \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k)$ then $M(n)=\operatorname{O}\left(n^{\frac 12+\epsilon}\right)$ for every $\epsilon >0$ is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis ([Anderson 'On the Möbius function'](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa59/aa5931.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How is $1.$ conjectural? One can replace the summation with the inverse zeta function and evaluate it at $s = 0$. The estimate of Merten's function precludes the conjecture anyway, no?

Comment: @user02138: Well if you look at the picture of the [Mertens function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mertens-big.svg) you'll notice that the function is (randomly) oscillating with increasing amplitude so that it is very probably divergent (I am not saying that a kind of 'pseudo-limit' isn't $-2$ but a limit requires convergence that seems unlikely here...)

Comment: $(2)$ was first proved by von Mangoldt (1897). In 1899, Landau gave a *much* simpler proof in his dissertation. Also in 1899, de la Vallée Poussin gave a simpler proof than von Mangoldt's. Not as simple as Landau's, but de la Vallée Poussin proved more, $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = O\biggl(\frac{1}{\log x}\biggr)\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for the correction and additional information!

Answer (score 2):

This paper uses very unfortunate notations: most of the functions (Rₖ, Tₖ, etc.) have a hidden parameter N (which limits the summation in n).  So even when you think that some terms do not depend on N, they do!  In most of the places in this paper, N<∞, so the question of convergence in n does not arise…

One should keep in mind that the main purpose of all the formulas in this paper is *to calculate with sufficient precision* for the plots in the paper.  As far as I can see it *today*, their strategy is:

- Choose N so that the summation of (4) (saying π(x) = ∑ₙ μ(n) f(ⁿ√x)/n) is exact (due to f(x)=0 for x<2);
- Use this N in the last summand ∑ₙ₌₁ᴺ μ(n)/n · li(ⁿ√x^ρ) of (19);
- Show that the second summand of (19) has a limit (see (32),(33) above) when N → ∞;
- Show that the first summand in (19) *differs from* ∑ₙ₌₁ᴺ μ(n) by a term converging when N → ∞.

So the calculations in the formulas (32) and (33) are only a glazing on the cake: the terms with a mysterious dependence on N (in
the last summand of (19)) are completely ignored (analytically), and dealt with numerically.

(Additionally, they put an extra condition on N, that ∑ₙ₌₁ᴺ μ(n) = -2 (after (36)).  Their rationale is completely unclear: why do
they care about decay rate in log x if they have a precise formula?!)