# Could someone explain how the Gram series relates to Riemann's function?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I was reading an [article](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html) on the distribution primes which mentions the following equation for Riemann's function $R(x)$:

$$R(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\text{li}(x^{1/n}) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k k!\zeta(k+1)}$$

Here's what the article says:

> The last form above for $R(x)$ is the Graham series and is an
>   excellent way to calculate this function.

I checked Wikipedia but I could not find any article on the Gram series.  Could someone provide information on the Gram series, what it is, and how it relates to $R(x)$.

---

Edit: The article I was reading incorrectly calls the Gram Series, the "Graham Series".  I have changed the spelling in each case except for the quote from the article.

Comment: This should be the [Gram series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramSeries.html) but convergence won't be as good as announced since fast for $|\ln x|<1$ but slow for $|\ln x|\gg 1$ (with very large terms as for the exponential in fact).

Comment: Thanks.  That would explain why I was having trouble finding information.

Comment: Glad it helped. I used the Gram series to produce the [animation at the bottom](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/encoding1.htm) (it required more than $100$ digits precision I think).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be the [Gram series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramSeries.html) but convergence will not be as good as announced since fast for $|\ln x|<1\,$ but slow for $|\ln x|\gg 1$ (with very large terms appearing as $k$ grows as for the exponential expansion).

Concerning a derivation let's [note](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#E8) that $\;\text{li}(x)=\text{Ei}(\ln x)\;$ and (from [DLMF $(6.6.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6)
$$\text{Ei}(s)=\gamma+\ln s+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{s^k}{k!\,k}$$
allowing us to go from the first to the second series (this is Berndt's derivation in Ramanujan's Notebooks IV p.$127$):
\begin{align}
R(x) &:= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\text{li}(x^{1/n})\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\text{Ei}\left(\frac 1n\,\ln x\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left(\gamma-\ln n+\ln\ln x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k!k\,n^k}\right)\\
&= (\gamma+\ln\ln x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\ln n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k!\,k\,n^k},\ (*)\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k!\,k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{k+1}}\\
& = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k k!\zeta(k+1)}\\
\end{align}

$(*)$ Using the well known facts (by Landau) :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}&=0\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\ln n&=-1\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}&=\frac 1{\zeta(s)}\\
\end{align}
It would seem that the two first series could be deduced from the third one ([obtained from the Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Mathematical_series)) but the first one is in fact ["as deep as" the PNT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151276/21783).